# unitarily invariant subspaces

Tags: polynomials, representation-theory, irreducible-polynomials, orthogonal-matrices

If $U_1$ is the group of unit norm complex scalars and $V$ is a subspace of complex variable polynomials. If $f(uz)\in V$ for $u\in U_1$ and $f\in V$, why $f(Uz)\in V$ for $f\in V$ and $U\in U(\mathbb{C}^n)$.
{It was written this is true since elements of $U_1$ can commute with elements of $U(\mathbb{C}^n)$ but I can not understand why?!}

Comment: What is $U(\mathbb{C}^n)$?

Comment: complex unitary matrices of dimension $n\times n$.

Comment: What kind of object is $f(Uz)$? You are plugging in a matrix into a polynomial?

Comment: $U\in (\mathbb{C}^n)$ and $z=(z_1,\cdots,z_n)^t\in \mathbb{C}^n$, so $Uz$ is well defined.  $f$ is a complex variable polynomial on $\mathbb{C}^n$.